# JS code after for loop runs before for loop finishes

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I have a javascript application running on NodeJS. For context I am using the express framework as this is meant to be our backend. I have a chunk of code which is meant to get data from a database, filter it and then send it back to the client. Instead, the filtering happens AFTER the response is sent, meaning the client is getting incorrect data. The code is below.

```
let resultArray = [];
const bulkSearchPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  for (let index = 0; index < input.length; index++) {
    collectionPool.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE ' + type + ' = $1', [input[index]], (err2, result2) => { // Make a query for each input user is trying to search for
      if (err2) console.log("Error in bulk search: " + err2);

      else {
        if (result2.rows.length > 0) { // If input user searched for was found
          pool.query('UPDATE users SET usedsearches = usedsearches + 1 WHERE id = $1', [result.rows[0].id]); // Increments used searches
          // The code below will filter useless key value pairs. For example if username: null then there is not a reason to send it back to the client
          let filteredArray = [];
          for (let index = 0; index < result2.rows.length; index++) {
            let array = Object.entries(result2.rows[index]);
            let filtered = array.filter(([key, value]) => value != null);
            let filteredObject = Object.fromEntries(filtered);
            filteredArray.push(filteredObject);
            resultArray.push(filteredObject);
          }
          console.log("a"); // This should run first.
        }
      }
    });
  }
  resolve("ok");
})

bulkSearchPromise.then((value) => {
  console.log("b"); // This should run second
  return res.json({
    status: 'success',
    content: resultArray
  }); // resultArray should be populated after the filtering above. Instead it is empty.
})
```

When the endpoint is hit the output will always be

```
username
b
a
```

What I need is for the for loop to run first and then after resultArray is populated, return it back to the client.

I've tried wrapping this code into a promise, but that hasnt helped either as 'resolve("ok")' is still called before the for loop completes.

Comment: You need to wrap every individual `collectionPool.query` call in a promise, and resolve each promise from the *asynchronous* callback.

Comment: what library is this that provides you these `.query()` methods? Are you sure they don't have a Promise version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your promise is resolving before `collectionPool.query` is done.

The for loop only runs after `collectionPool.query` is done but you are resolving the promise before it.
Note that `collectionPool.query` is async and the its callback will only run when the web-api is finished (if this concept is murky check this out http://latentflip.com/loupe)

### Option 1:

Move `resolve()` inside the `collectionPool.query` (where the `console.log("a");`) call back and call `resolve(filteredObject)`.
In addition you should `reject(err2)` when `err2` is not null (not just console)

### Option 2:

you can use [`Util.Promisify`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html) to transform `collectionPool.query` to promise base API which will save you the hustle of manually transform

```
const util = require('util');

util.promisify(collectionPool.query)(QUERY)
  .then(queryRes => { 
     /* logic to refine queryRes to object */
     return filteredObject;
   })
```

---

in both options you can omit the `resultArray` from your code. if you `resolve(filteredObject)` or `return filteredObject;` in `then()` you will be able to access this data on the next `then` (the value in `bulkSearchPromise.then((value)`).